# Distribution of concatenating two uniform random numbers

Tags: probability, statistics, uniform-distribution

Suppose I have two indepent random number generators $RNG_1$ and $RNG_2$, each output random numbers of range $[0, 2^{31}-1]$ with equal probability. I shall make a new random number generator of uniform distribution $[0, 2^{63}-1]$ by sampling two random numbers $r_1$ and $r_2$ from $RNG_1$ and $RNG_2$ respectively, then concatenating them together:

1. Sample a random number $r_1$ from $RNG_1$
2. Sample a random number $r_2$ from $RNG_2$
3. return a new random number $r = 2^{32} r_1 + r_2$

I see there are already a lot of such idea, like

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/965010/86492

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/593271/86492

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/179066/86492

However, they don't give a reason why it works.

So I'd like to see a formal proof... Thanks~

========================================

Edit

Suppose $RNG_1$ and $RNG_2$ have perfect uniform distribution (i.e., they output numbers with equal probability)

Comment: I'm not sure what you want proved.  (What does it mean for it to "work"?)  Are these pseudorandom number generators (PRNGs) or perfect RNGs?  (PRNGs are never perfect.) Do you want a proof that the 64-bit numbers are as random as each of the two 32-bit PRNGs?  (In fact, they might not be as random as the each of the two PRNGs.  Some PRNGs can exhibit correlations.  There are various reasons for this, and there are a number of relevant articles.)  By the way, cs.stackexchanges is also a good place for this kind of question.

Comment: Step 3. is confusing.  Do you mean $r=r_1+2^{32}r_2$?

Comment: @Mars Yes suppose they are perfect RNGs. I have added a  note to make this clearer.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Yes, I've edited the question.

Comment: Have you tried proving it for the case in which each generates a single bit at random? It easily generalizes from there.

Comment: One minor issue.   The lowest bit for $r_1$ will always be a $1$.  to get an exact distribution it should be $0$ half the time.

Comment: @HankIgoe I guess I've got your idea. Will try, thanks.